# Input type number does not allow comma separator

Tags: html

I have a number input field:

```html
<input type="number" class="field" min="0" step="0.01" required>
```

My language is en

As soon as I type `12,` the value returns nothing it's empty, not NaN, undefined or 0 just an empty log

[image]

Is there a way to allow both comma and period? Or do I have to fallback to a simple input with some custom validation?

Comment: You should use masked inputs. See - https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: use type as text instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this custom validation form for `number` you can allow it to insert comma `,` and dot `.` except for letters and other symbols. Thanks

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function filter_letters_and_symbols(evt){

  var hold = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);

  if((/[a-z A-Z*!@#$%^&*()_/[\]}=+><{?":;'"|]/.test(hold))){

    evt.preventDefault();

  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="field" min="0" step="0.01" onkeypress="filter_letters_and_symbols(event)" required>
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to do?

Comment: As your situation, you cannot allow it to do with a comma `,` because it's a type of `number` so what I'll recommend to you is you should use `onkeypress` or whatever you want with a type of `text`, the code provided above is the solution of your issue. Thanks